# Set persistent environment variables when installing my custom python package with pip

Tags: python, pip, setup.py

I have a setup.py script for installing my custom python package, which looks like the following:

```
import subprocess
import sys
import os
...



# setting enviornment variables so that they persist across sessions
env_var_string = ""
if os.name == 'posix':  #  linux
    env_var_string = env_var_string + "export " + "TEST_VAR" + "=" + TEST_VAR + "\n"
    env_var_string = env_var_string + "export " + "TEST_VAR_2" + "=" + TEST_VAR_2 + "\n"
if os.name == 'nt':  # windows
    env_var_string = env_var_string + "setx " + "TEST_VAR" + " " + TEST_VAR + "\r\n"
    env_var_string = env_var_string + "setx " + "TEST_VAR_2" + " " + TEST_VAR_2 + "\r\n"
subprocess.Popen(env_var_string, shell=True).wait()

print('Set TEST_VAR to ' + os.environ["TEST_VAR"])
print('Set TEST_VAR_2 to ' + os.environ["TEST_VAR_2"])
setup (name             = PACKAGE_NAME,
       version          = VERSION,
       author           = AUTHOR,
       author_email     = AUTHOR_EMAIL,
       description      = DESCRIPTION,
       long_description = LONG_DESCRIPTION,
       install_requires=required,
       packages=find_packages(where="src"),
       package_dir={'': 'src'},
       python_requires='>=3.6',
       )
```

However, it seems that the environment variables are not properly set. When I run:

```
pip install -e .
```

I get the following error:

```
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [9 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "/home/user/test/setup.py", line 50, in <module>
          print('Set TEST_VAR to ' + os.environ["TEST_VAR"])
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/os.py", line 675, in __getitem__
          raise KeyError(key) from None
      KeyError: 'TEST_VAR'
      test
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

Using simply

os.environ["TEST_VAR"] = TEST_VAR

instead of the subprocess.Popen call, like:

```
import os
...


os.environ["TEST_VAR"] = TEST_VAR
os.environ["TEST_VAR_2"] = TEST_VAR_2

print('Set TEST_VAR to ' + os.environ["TEST_VAR"])
print('Set TEST_VAR_2 to ' + os.environ["TEST_VAR_2"])
setup (name             = PACKAGE_NAME,
       version          = VERSION,
       author           = AUTHOR,
       author_email     = AUTHOR_EMAIL,
       description      = DESCRIPTION,
       long_description = LONG_DESCRIPTION,
       install_requires=required,
       packages=find_packages(where="src"),
       package_dir={'': 'src'},
       python_requires='>=3.6',
       )
```

makes the installation work, but the variables are not available after the installation process is completed, i.e., if:

```
echo $TEST_VAR
```

I get a blank line.

How can I properly set environment variables from the setup.py script that are persistent and visible by other processes that I run after installing the package?

NOTE: I am running the pip install within a virtual environment. Would exporting the variables within bashrc give me issues, if I also source from venv/bin/activate/ ?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: I have found a workaround using https://pypi.org/project/python-dotenv/, but any suggestion on not using external libraries is still very much appreciated!